# OutOfMemoryError on Eclipse using a webapp when compiling on browser

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I receive the following error when I am trying to compile a webapp on browser:

```
[ERROR] OutOfMemoryError: Increase heap size or lower gwt.jjs.maxThreads
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.StringWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.print(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.AbstractTextOutput.printAndCount(AbstractTextOutput.java:161)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.AbstractTextOutput.print(AbstractTextOutput.java:117)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor._nameRef(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:1120)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.visit(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:645)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsNameRef.traverse(JsNameRef.java:121)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:467)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:444)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsSourceGenerationVisitorWithSizeBreakdown.generateAndBill(JsSourceGenerationVisitorWithSizeBreakdown.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsReportGenerationVisitor.generateAndBill(JsReportGenerationVisitor.java:109)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsSourceGenerationVisitorWithSizeBreakdown.doAccept(JsSourceGenerationVisitorWithSizeBreakdown.java:63)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.visit(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:594)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsInvocation.traverse(JsInvocation.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:467)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:444)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsSourceGenerationVisitorWithSizeBreakdown.generateAndBill(JsSourceGenerationVisitorWithSizeBreakdown.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsReportGenerationVisitor.generateAndBill(JsReportGenerationVisitor.java:109)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsSourceGenerationVisitorWithSizeBreakdown.doAccept(JsSourceGenerationVisitorWithSizeBreakdown.java:63)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.accept(JsVisitor.java:109)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsToStringGenerationVisitor.visit(JsToStringGenerationVisitor.java:445)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsExprStmt.traverse(JsExprStmt.java:41)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doTraverse(JsVisitor.java:467)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsVisitor.doAccept(JsVisitor.java:444)
               [ERROR] Out of memory; to increase the amount of memory, use the -Xmx flag at startup (java -Xmx128M ...)
            [ERROR] Unrecoverable exception, shutting down
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.ThreadedPermutationWorkerFactory$ThreadedPermutationWorker.compile(ThreadedPermutationWorkerFactory.java:56)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.PermutationWorkerFactory$Manager$WorkerThread.run(PermutationWorkerFactory.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
            [ERROR] Not all permutation were compiled , completed (0/1)
      [WARN] recompile failed
      [WARN] continuing to serve previous version
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error because I have modified the run configuration of the project in Arguments, VM arguments -Xmx1024m.

Also, my eclipse.ini looks like this:

```
-startup
../../../.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
../../../.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-install
C:/Users/ANDREI/eclipse/jee-mars2/eclipse
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_71/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting MaxPermSpace too : -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Comment: where? at run configurations on VM arguments?

Comment: Yes in eclipse -> run configurations -> on arguments tab -> VM arguments:

Comment: same error, but I don't understand why it says 128m in the error description ("[ERROR] Out of memory; to increase the amount of memory, use the -Xmx flag at startup (java -Xmx128M ...)")

Comment: I see you are using java 8 version : C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_71/bin is that true? in that case try MetaSpaceSize : -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m Actually in Java 8 there is no limit on this but try that.

Comment: yes, i am using java 8 and no, unfortunately i still receive that error

Comment: are you sure your configuration is updated with new VM arguments? Restart eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything above 512/1024M?  I have mine set in the 2-4g range...

Comment: yes, 2g, but the problem is that I reinstalled eclipse and now doesn't work, before it didn't work with 512m, but worked perfectly with 1g

Comment: That's kind of strange...I'm not sure if this will help at all but usually when I'm running into weird issues like this, I delete the gwt cache and then delete the projects from the workspace and reimport them.  Make sure if you delete them from the workspace you don't have the delete from disk check box enabled.